# Delete rows of a UITableView in iOS 7.1.1 brings to a NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7.1, ios8.1

I having a strange bug in my application and I cannot find an explanation for the crash.

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

The scenario is the following. I have a `UITableView` where rows can be deleted by means of "Swipe to delete" functionality. The code I'm using is like:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // 1) Remove the object from the model
        NSUInteger previousNumberOfItems = [self.items count];
        [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSUInteger currentNumberOfItems = [self.items count];

        // 2) Update the table
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

        if (self.editModeEnabled && (previousNumberOfItems >= kMaxNumberOfItems) && (currentNumberOfItems < kMaxNumberOfItems)) {
            NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: currentNumberOfItems inSection:0], nil];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }

        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

`self.editModeEnabled` is set only when the client tap on an external button. So, when in "Swipe to delete" functionality, the `if()` statement is not executed.

The `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` looks like this

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSUInteger rows = [self.items count];
    if (self.editModeEnabled) {
        // Calculate the rows if in edit mode
        return rows++;
    }
    // If "Swipe to delete"
    return rows;
}
```

The client has an iPad with iOS 7.1.1 and he says the app crashes whenever he commits a delete (I verified with the log). On the contrary, I have an iPad with iOS 8.1.3 and I cannot replicate the same behavior. The app works in the correct manner.

Do you have any hint on how to fix this? My first step should be to download an Xcode with a simulator with the same iOS version.

P.S. If you are aware of some buggy behavior of iOS 7.1.1 version, let me know.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for you answer but the problem arises only on iOS 7.1.1 ;-(

Comment: What does the `// Do something else if the table view is in editing mode` part do?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch That part is used when the table is set in edit mode by means of a `UIButton`. I updated the code. Thanks

Comment: As I thought it contains `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Your problem is probably that this condition becomes true, but your dataSource (i.e. `numberOfRowsInSection`) doesn't expect that. This is an attempt to implement something like paging, isn't it?  If so I would not necessarily look at iOS 7.1.1. Test it with the edge cases, i.e. kMaxNumberOfItems, kMaxNumberOfItems-1, kMaxNumberOfItems+1 items in your dataSource. It's probably an off-by-one error in your paging logic. (Unfortunately I can't really wrap my head around these either)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Thanks. A sort of. Anyway I don't understand why in iOS 8.1.3 I do not have any crash. The `self.editModeEnabled` is set whenever a user tap on that external button. So, this scenario cannot be verified on "Swipe to delete". They are in `&&` condition.